# Copying cell to other cells in MS Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts

I want to copy a cell's data to the 4 cells below it.

ex: If I have 'apple', I need

apple
apple
apple
apple
apple

Please suggest to me a short cut that will do this.

Comment: select 4 cells bellow and press Ctrl-D...

Comment: if you are averse to dragging the mouse there is very little that can be done , probably you could write a macro

Comment: @bensiu +1 never knew that one. Plus selecting the cell above the four, probably was understood.

Answer (score 3):

Or you can just click+drag the lower-right corner of the cell, 4 cells down, the old-fashioned way.

Answer (score 0):

Select "apple", hold shift, push down arrow a bunch, push ctrl-d.

If you want the same amount of rows of "apples" as there are in a neighboring column: click on the apple, shift+right arrow, ctrl + shift + down arrow (now two columns are highlighted), shift + left arrow (now just the empty column with apple on top is highlighted), ctrl+d

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just CTRL+C the apple cell and select what ever cells you want and CTRL+V ? This should be the faster method, no?

You can select other cells by:

- clicking the target cell
- click on a starting cell and drag to get a range
- ctrl and click to add to selected cells.

Use any of the above combination and you can select any cell you want.